# Проблема выборки конечных узлов дерева из SQLite под Android

Tags: cursor, android, null, дерево, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
Имеется база в SQLite (на эмуляторе), состоящая из одной таблицы. Структура таблицы сделана так, чтобы хранить дерево (отец-сын-внук и т.д.). В качестве образца использовал вот эту http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/17286/match=managing+trees+database и эту http://websiteprog.ru/sozdanie_derevev_xranenie_dannyx_na_primere_kategorij ссылки.
Вот содержимое базы:

```
id = 0; parent_id = null; name = father; path = 0/; 
id = 1; parent_id = 0; name = son; path = 0/1/; 
id = 2; parent_id = 0; name = daughter; path = 0/2/; 
id = 3; parent_id = 1; name = grandson; path = 0/1/3/;
```

Вроде все работает, только не получается вывести все конечные узлы/leafs (те, которые не являются родителями). Для вывода листьев использую запрос:

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE id not in (SELECT parent_id from tbl_category)".
```

Однако сообщается, что курсор равен null, т.е. как понимаю ничего подходящего в базе не нашел. Запрос `"SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE id in (SELECT parent_id from tbl_category)"` работает и выдает (всех родителей):

```
id = 0; parent_id = null; name = father; path = 0/; 
id = 1; parent_id = 0; name = son; path = 0/1/;
```

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

UPD: добавляю код Java

```
void logCursor(Cursor c) {
    try {
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String str;
                do {
                    str = "";
                    for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
                        str = str.concat(cn + " = "
                                + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");

                    }
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                "An exception has occured in logCursor: " + e.toString());
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCLick button ---");
    dbh = new DBHelper(this);
    db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

    String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE id not in (SELECT parent_id from tbl_category)";

    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectQuery, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                "An excpetion has occured in onClick: " + e.toString());
    }
    logCursor(c);
}
```

Comment: @aleksandr_mai, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: курсор не должен быть равен null даже в случае, когда он ни чего не нашел.    
Дайте Java код.

Comment: Да нет, как раз null, когда ничего не находит

Comment: Раз c == null, значит у вас возникает эксцепшен в строке     
c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectQuery, null);

Comment: Не возникает. LogCat выводит: --- OnClick --- на следующей строке Cursor is null (из logCursor() в ветке else) и больше ничего, только две эти строки и все.